# iptables-restore Hangs when first run after a reboot

Tags: iptables, ubuntu-14.04

On my first run following a reboot, I run `iptables-restore < rules`
as root. It hangs, and refuses to return the console to me without a ctrl-c.

However, looking at `iptables -L` through a different console shows the rules were applied! So it seems to be working at least partially. However, running the command in if-pre-up.d does not yield success.

running Ubuntu Server 14.04

Edit: For those who may read this in the future, iptables-restore was not hanging, per se. It was simply not printing out a prompt without *any* key being pressed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be because of the DNS, can you check if you can resolve some of the domain names that you have in your rules?

Comment: That's exactly it! More specifically, I was applying the rule before the interfaces went up, so it couldn't resolve the DNS query.